# I want to install docker offline in my Linux Rhel machine. There is no internet connection in my machine

Tags: docker

As there is no internet connection in my machine i can't install docker directly from internet like "yum install docker" i need to download rpm file and install it offline. by using sudo rpm -i rpmfilename. Hence i did like this and now docker client Engine is installed seems. But docker daemon is not yet installed. So i don't know how to install it.

While doing, docker version it shows only "client Engine version" not "Server Engine version". I believe it should show both client and Server Engine version. Can you please help me how to install docker properly offline in Linux Rhel 7 machine.

```
docker version

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.9
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        9d988398e7
 Built:             Fri May 15 00:25:27 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

$ rpm -qa | grep docker
docker-ce-cli-19.03.9-3.el7.x86_64
docker-ce-selinux-17.03.3.ce-1.el7.noarch

$ rpm -qa | grep container
containerd.io-1.2.2-3.el7.x86_64

$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.9, build 9d988398e7


$ service docker status
Redirecting to / bin/ syst`enter code here`emctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/ usr / lib/ system d/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http ://docs.docker.com
```

Comment: Which binary did you install?

Comment: Your user might not have access to the docker socket, try `sudo docker version` if this works, add your user to the `docker` group (you have to log out and log in again for this change to take effect).